# ebean-orm.xml not reloading after change

Tags: playframework, docker, ebean, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.8 and Ebean ORM. I have to mention that the server runs from a ***Docker Container***.

I created `ebean-orm.xml` file for mapping entities. But this file is not reloading after making changes and restarting the server.

Why is this happening?

Thank you

My *build.sbt*

```
name := """app"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 javaJdbc,
 javaEbean,
 cache,
 javaWs
)
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1004-jdbc4"
```

My *application.conf*

```
include "database.conf" // just connection on postgres
evolutionplugin=disabled
//Ebean conf
ebean.default="models.*"
datasource.default=default 
datasource.default.username=XX
datasource.default.password=XX
datasource.default.databaseUrl="XX" 
datasource.default.databaseDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG
logger.root=ERROR
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=DEBUG
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not reloading? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Oh, thank you for the interest. In fact, when update this file and refresh the navigator, changes not taken into account by the framework.

Comment: You mean the server, not the framework. How are you starting the server? With _run_ or _~run_?

Comment: Yes, the server sorry. The server start with _activator run_

Comment: We need more details like: your _build.sbt_ file + _application.conf_ file + _ebean.properties_ file (if you created one). Update your answer with the content of these files.

Comment: When i restart the docker container (so the server) the modifications of the file are taken into account but when i modify the file while the server turns the modifications are not taken into account. It looks like there is a cache.